# Setting background image from own domain shows nothing - external domain works

Tags: html, css, image

This is super, duper weird from my perspective.

I'm setting up a website where I have a banner. I set the background image using the `background-image` property.

My challenge is: when I have two images with same dimensions, it doesn't work when I load using own domain, but works on external domain.

**MY CHALLENGE:**

I have this banner on my page:

[image]

Background is set like this:

[image]

Now this is kinda weird, since the image actually works on this URL and instead I get a black background (no image):

[image]

If I use a different image from a third party URL that has exactly same dimensions:

[image]

And I replace this in the CSS:

[image]

Then everything is fine and the background works!

So my question is:
What on earth is going on? I obviously assume I've went crazy and need to go home and sleep since there must be something super obvious going on, but I need your help to tell me what's wrong with me.

Comment: can you show demo link?

Comment: Sure @MuhammadAkberKhan - it's www.asano.dk . Didn't post to make post a bit more generic and future proff, but you can see it here.

Comment: As I have checked the image is loading in the section you mentioned

Comment: @PraveenKumar What? Can you send screenshot? We are talking about this area right: http://prntscr.com/g77tf3 ?

Comment: If you clear background from`.overlay::after` you will see the background. I don't know where the problem is?

Comment: you have an overlay effect .overlay::after has background so only the image is not visible

Comment: @Huelfe Try to replace the background-image with an external URL and it will show :-)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know. However, if I simply change the URL of the actual image to the external one, it shows. So the challenge is not we have .overlay::after, but the fact if i replace it with an external it fails.

Comment: It works for external also i have checked now

Comment: @PraveenKumar My point is. This works without modifying the .overlay::after if you use external image

Comment: My point is that the overlay effect has a dark background if you make the background transparent it will show. That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay effect hides your background image.

[image]

Kindly change the css

```
.overlay::after{
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: I know. However, if I simply change the URL of the actual image to the external one, it shows. So the challenge is not we have .overlay::after, but the fact if i replace it with an external it fails.

The whole idea is it creates a parallax-like feature, and the CSS works perfectly when I use a third party domain as my image.